# Error in downloading emulator in android studio in ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04, android-studio-3.0

I am using android studio 3.0 in ubuntu when i try to download emulator it says "your cpu does not support required features (VT-x or SVM)"

Comment: What CPU are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VMWare Fusion and I found that enabling hypervisor applicartions allowed me to run the emulator without much fuss.

Just go to your vm's settings > Processors & Memory > Advanced options
and enable hypervisor applications.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing this before adding emulator.

> Required libraries for 64-bit machines:
>   If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

If you are running 64-bit Fedora, the command is:

```
sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686
```

Installation [Guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html)